# vuex subscribe to individual mutation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Is it possible to subscribe to an individual mutation?

Instead of:

```
this.$store.subscribe((mutation, state) => {
   if(mutation === 'someMutation'){
       doSomething()
   }
})
```

I would like something like this:

```
this.$store.subscribe('someMutation', state => {
    doSomething()
})
```

Comment: u might need to check https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#watch

Comment: No it will run for all mutations unfortunately: [docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#subscribe)

Comment: How about using mapState in the component for just the particular data in your store state and then using a watch on that?

Comment: as @MikeHarrison mention in the docs and also as you can see in the vuex code https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/dev/src/store.js (line 103). vuex just call any function in sub arrays without checking for mutation. so vuex actually not support it. of course you can go behind the secenes and build your own module/function which will handle it. and use it.

Answer (score 4):

From vuex docs:

> The handler is called after every mutation and receives the mutation
> descriptor and post-mutation state as arguments.

It will react to all mutations, So you only can implement with your own conditional.

Answer (score 3):

How about wrapping the method you have somewhere in Vue prototype?

So instead of having:

```
this.$store.subscribe((mutation, state) => {
   if(mutation === 'someMutation'){
       doSomething()
   }
})
```

You would have something like:

```
Vue.prototype.subscribeMutation = function(someMutation, someFunction) {
       this.$store.subscribe((mutation, state) => {
       if(mutation === someMutation){
           someFunction(state)
       }
    })
}
```

I haven't tested the code, but you should be able to get the working result easily.

Comment: In Vue 3 you want to do if(mutation.type === someMutation) {...}

Comment: this implementation has some flaws, you should also return unsubscribe callback which returned from `this.$store.subscribe`

Answer (score -5):

Try something like this:

```
this.$store.subscribe(mutation => {
                if (mutation.type === 'setData') {
//  do something here
                }
            });
```

Comment: Code only answers are low quality and subject to deletion, there should always be at least one or two sentences explaining what question you are addressing and some information about what is going on.

Comment: This is pretty much the same that I am already doing. (i.e. the first code sample in my question). I was looking for a solution like the second sample